# Compile piece of code dynamically and add it to the current class

Tags: c#, codedom, runtime-compilation

I want to create several properties on the fly inside the class' constructor and add them to the current class.
The property's template is the following

```
public [PropertyType] [PropertyName]
{
get {return Container.Resolve();}
}
```

I've read a little about CodeDom and Reflection.Emit but haven't been able to figure out
how to use them in this particular use case.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm elaborating on the purpose due to the number of questions...
I'm trying to implement the base class for a view model locator. The binding in xaml is achieved through referring to a property by its path, therefore it MUST be a property.
The types and names of the properties to be added are known only at runtime, therefore I'm using reflection to get them. In short, I need an example of taking a piece of code and compiling it dynamically into the given class.

Comment: How would that call work? Did you forget to add a parameter to `Resolve()`?

Comment: The Resolve() method would work without parameters. It's not the issue here...

Comment: Why do you want to add properties to the class? To call them you'd need to use reflection. And if you're using reflection then why don't you use it to simply execute the content you want in that property getter?

Comment: I get that it's not the point of the question, but I'm curious: how do you intend `Resolve()` to work? If you want to use something like `StackTrace`, that won't work because of inlining.

Comment: In fact, it has worked. That's exactly the way I implemented it

Comment: In Debug builds, it will work. In Release build, it's likely that it won't work.

Comment: It works even in Release mode. Just checked it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're under C# 4, you can use the new dynamic features for that. Use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) to add properties to your object dynamically. If you then refer to them in XAML, they will get resolved correctly.

In any case, it's not possible to modify existing class. What you can is to create a new class, which can inherit from existing class, and add the properties to that. You should be able to bind to them from XAML.

Comment: do you happen to have any code sample to expan on this approach?

Comment: Which one? Using C#4 and dynamic objects or creating new class dynamically?

Comment: thanks a lot for the clue. It really does the trick. I didn't even need to create a new class as I simply made the existing one inherit from the DynamicObject. The code is much cleaner now

Answer (score 1):

alternative approach:

you could implement ICustomTypeDescriptor and provide the additional properties

link: [Issue with Grid data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655246/issue-with-grid-data-binding/5655852#5655852)

Answer (score 0):

Bind your xaml stuff to somthing like xml and change xml in the runtime

Comment: In such a case the Container.Resolve() won't work.
The property constraint is a RIGID one

Answer (score -1):

You can create new calss and inherit it from the current class ,the new class can have the on the fly properties and base class functionality

yes its possible take look at this 
[Help required in adding new methods, properties into existing classes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937807/help-required-in-adding-new-methods-properties-into-existing-classes-dynamically)

Comment: Is it possible to create the new properties within the same class?

Comment: the asnwers you linked to don't add anything to existing class.